# Custom List View for User

Tags: list-view

I have a SP list where the user assigns the reviewer (people picker) and the workflow emails the user to notify them of an invoice they have to approve.

However, there are instances in this process where the user could potentially receive up to 50 emails (1 for each invoice).

Is there a way to create a customized view to show only items that are assigned to the user logged in? If so, users could simply go to the list to check if they have any invoices to approve.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by setting [Me] filter by modifying/creating a view. Some [additional information](http://sharefort.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/using-me-filter-in-sharepoint.html) about the [Me] filter
[image]